# VPN on server for certain outgoing connections

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I have a server running openvpn for outgoing connections. However, once I start openvpn, I lose SSH, HTTP access to the server's IP. This is expected I guess, but is there a way to circumvent the VPN connection when connecting to these ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a routing problem: You have set OpenVPN to replace the default router (handling "normal" traffic) with the OpenVPN-Connection's. If you configure OpenVPN to use static routes, your normal traffic will again work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! It appears I'm a bit in over my head here. Before I go deeper down the rabbit hole, is this something I can configure fully on the server? I don't have access routers or hardware in between.

Comment: Yes you can (TM)! Here is a crash course: Your network traffic is sent in packets. Every packet, that doesn't belong in the LAN will be sent to a router (preconfigured by your ISP) for delivery. Your system knows about this "default router". When OpenVPN connects, it is set to override this "default router" setting - resulting in loss of internet connection.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! That makes a lot of sense. So I can change the OpenVPN configuration to not override this default router? Using static routes?

Comment: Again: Yes you can. Look at your OpenVPN config file and search for `gateway` post what you found.

Comment: Thanks. Not finding `gateway` in the config file though. Here it is in it's entirety: [http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9URBnCsF](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9URBnCsF)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you: Your server acts as an OpenVPN **client**, not as an OpenVPN **server**. In this case, the start of the file is relevant: "# Specify that we are a client and that we will be pulling certain config file directives from the server." This includes the router settings.

Comment: You are not out of luck though: After connecting, you can run `route add default gw ...` and rectify this. Talk with your OpenVPN sever's admin about that - whatroutes he needs.